# Why is it so important to load the Keras MNIST with a pair of tuples?

Tags: python, keras

In the documentation, they recommend using this line to load the `mnist`:

```
from keras.datasets import mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
```

If you don't use tuples or lists, it will raise an error:

> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 2)

It also works with lists. Why is it so important to use tuples or lists? With `sklearn`, it isn't a problem to use

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)
```

So why can't it work here?

Comment: The result is a two-tuple (of two-tuples), so for unpacking you need exactly two "receivers" on the left side. It might be a bit confusing that these receivers are also unpacked immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [`keras.mnist.load_data()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/1cf0898dd4331baf93fe77205550f2c2e6c90ee5/tensorflow/python/keras/datasets/mnist.py#L27-L55) it just returns two tuples exactly. So you need exactly two tuples or lists for the unpacking to happen correctly.

But if you look at [`scikit.model_selection.train_test_split`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/bf24c7e3d6d768dddbfad3c26bb3f23bc82c0a18/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py#L2018), it does this smartly by creating a chain from iteratables using `itertools.chain`, which allows you to do the unpacking using four elements.

If you want `keras.mnist.load_data()` to work similarly do the following.

```
from itertools import chain
x1, y1, x2, y2 = chain.from_iterable(tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data())
```